# Unable to download json data table

Tags: json, ajax, download

I'm trying to get/download data, seen on this page:

https://80.95.112.246/aplikace/monras/tabulky/svz.json?id=1159

using linux command line tools (ubuntu server, no display, no gui, remote ssh connection only). I've tried every possible tool without success (including PhantomJS). The only way I was able to get the numbers from the table was Firefox "save complete page" on a Windows PC.

Can someone help me with this? I need to store the table data in a text file on the server.

Comment: No one knows a solution? Please change the URL IP address to www.sujb.cz , if the link does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is simply to save the file onto the machine, run:

```
curl https://80.95.112.246/aplikace/monras/tabulky/svz.json?id=1159 -o svz.json
```

The downloaded   file will be saved as `svz.json` in the current directory.

Comment: If you would test your answer before posting here, you would find, that it saves the page **without the table**. (If it complains about a certificate, please change the IP address in the URL to www.sujb.cz.)